# How do I add a class to elements preceding a clicked class?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML in which I am building up star-based voting. I want it to where if the user clicks on the fourth star all the stars up to and including the one they clicked have the new class that would show the stars "lit up" such that they have the CSS class called `jquery-ratings-full`?

```
<div id="starRating">
     <img class="jquery-ratings-star" id="star1" />
     <img class="jquery-ratings-star" id="star2" />
     <img class="jquery-ratings-star" id="star3" />
     <img class="jquery-ratings-star" id="star4" />
     <img class="jquery-ratings-star" id="star5" />
</div>
```

Comment: look at `.prev()` or `.prevAll()` in jQuery

Comment: Or use Pure CSS: http://kubyshkin.ru/posts/star-rating-input-pure-css.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.prevAll()` - selects all the previous siblings
`.addBack()` - adds the `this` element to the selection, so you also fill the clicked star.

You can first remove the fill from all stars, but this is not necessary if the user can't change it's vote (rate again).

```
$('.jquery-ratings-star').click(function(){
   $('.jquery-ratings-star').removeClass('jquery-ratings-full');
   $(this).prevAll().addBack().addClass('jquery-ratings-full');     
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P8wrM/2/

Answer (score 5):

You can select previous siblings with [`.prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) and following siblings with [`.nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

```
$('.jquery-ratings-star').click(function() {
    $(this)
      .prevAll().addBack().addClass('jquery-ratings-full').end().end()
      .nextAll().removeClass('jquery-ratings-full');
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you remove class for everything, i.e. `$(this).siblings().addBack().removeCLass('...').end()` and then add classes to the previous elements? :)

Comment: @Terry: Better in terms of what? There are so many ways to do a thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't double checked, but something like this ought to do the trick.

```
var stars = $(#starRating).children('img');

stars.click(function(e){
  var clickedIndex = $(e.target).index();

  // If you want user to be able to click a different star,
  // after they've already clicked one, do this first

  stars.removeClass('selected')    

  // Apply selected class to every star at or below the clicked index

  stars.each(function(){
    if ($(this).index() <= clickedIndex){
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
  });

  // Set a callback function to track or process rankings, if needed

  optionalCallback(clickedIndex);
});
```

Comment: Really? I really like my code comments in all caps.. because my code is never in caps so it helps my eyes see the comments even if they're deep in the code...

Didn't realize that was a faux pas... :\

Comment: FYI, `stars` is already a jQuery object, so you can replace `$(stars)` with `stars` (there is no point to pass it to jQuery *again*, or would you do `$($('#foo'))`?) The outer `.each` loop is completely unnecessary, just do `stars.click(...)`. The inner `.each ` loop can be simplified to `stars.slice(0, clickedIndex + 1).addClass('selected');`.

Comment: My comments ARE screaming in pain, because I wrote them so hard!!

Comment: Ok, I yield. Comments and downvotes have forced me to update my answer. Hopefully its not quite so disappointing to everybody now...